# Python Pickle object in Django model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pickle, django-orm

I would like to know what would be the simplest way to store pickle objects in PostgreSQL DB using Django ORM.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use pickle instead of something else, like for example what Django models give you out of the box? Pickle isn't terribly portable.

Comment: Please don't do that. You'll run into trouble if you update your Python version in the future. Just use JSON or something similar.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advise. Is there a module that converts a class object into json and could also be reconverted back into the original object ?

Comment: you can use something like `import json; json.dumps(ClassInstance.__dict__)`  restoring the class I'm less sure... Perhaps creating an alternative constructor and calling it with the dictionary?

Comment: ...but, again, _why_? You specifically say you're trying to store objects in a Postgres database. If they're Django models you can do that already, without bothering with JSON or any other serialization format.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**`BinaryField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield) to store pickled object.

From comments of the question, you can also use [**`JSONField`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield) to store dict from class instance. You can do it like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField

class YourModel(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()
```

Lets say you have a class like this(which you want to store):

```
class YourClass(object):
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Your Class: {}, {}, {}'.format(self.a, self.b, self.c)
```

Now you can generate dictionary like this:

```
some_instance = YourClass(a=1, b=2, c=3)
cls_dict = some_instance.__dict__
print(cls_dict)
# {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

y = YourModel(data=cls_dict)
y.save()
```

Now you can try restoring Class instance from dictionary like this:

```
y = YourModel.objects.first()
some_instance = YourClass()
some_instance.__dict__.update(y.data)

print(some_instance)

# 'Your Class: 1, 2, 3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not comment on wether or not it's wise to use pickled data in the database. But you can use the `django-picklefield` library to store pickled data:

https://pypi.org/project/django-picklefield/